# Working with Powertools MSXML 4.0 Issue

Tags: 2013-sp1, installation, powertools

I have installed Tridion 2013 SP1 on Windows 2012 R2.I
I want to install powertool to add users and other handful stuff.

Tried running installer for PowerTools 2013 SP1 which could not run on machine giving unknown errors, then tried manual approach and succeeded.

But when try to run any of powertool, it gives following error :

> Please install MSXML 4.0

We have MSXML4.0 SP3 installed, still this error happening.

When checked MSXML4.0 System Specification it does not include Windows 2012 R2.
I tried installing MSXML6.0 as well, but no luck overcoming error.

May i get some advice how to tickle situation here?

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: Are you certain this is from the PowerTools? I cannot find any such error. Is your CME working without PowerTools installed? Did you install the PowerTools from the link on this page? https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/

Answer (score 4):

If all else fails you can also install the PowerTools manually, see https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/GUIextensionIn8steps.aspx.

Or use Robert Curlette's lightweight installer script, see http://www.curlette.com/?cat=13.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the "msxml4.dll" is registered in the windows register (regedit.exe) into the local windows folder (like c:\windows\sysWOW64\msxml4.dll). If not, the installation has failed and the reference for the powertools does not exist. You should be able to install the xml properly, of not.. it might be an issue based on permissions.

Comment: Infact i have msxml3.dll, msxml3r.dll, msxml4.dll, msxml4r.dll, msxml6.dll, msxml6r.dll under c:\windows\sysWOW64